# Strange centering behaviour with nicematrix

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, rules, block, nicematrix

With the package `nicematrix` I try to create a `NiceTabular` to be able to work with blocks. While doing so, I made some interesting/strange observations.

The first thing, I realized: Blocks and rules do not fit together, as you can see in the following result:

[image]

Only one site fits to the rule, the other one goes too far.

So far, so good.

The strange behaviour in my opinion happens, when I look at the centering within these blocks: The horizontal heading is not centered to its block, but to the `\cmidrule`. Fine, this is good.
But on the contrary, the vertical heading is not centered to its `\vrule` but to the block boundaries.

To visualize that, I replaced the words "Headings" by some comparison strings and I drew some lines.

[image]

As a result, the horizontal heading is centered perfectly as intended, but the vertical centering is a bit too low. It should be centered with respect to the vrule as well.

Why is that difference and how can I achieve that the vertical centering fits to the rule as well? Thank you! :)

Here is my code for reproducing:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newcommand{\nicewidth}{\dimexpr .13333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{NiceTabular}{@{}wc{\nicewidth}!{\vrule}*{4}{wc{\nicewidth}}@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \Block[fill=red!15]{1-*}{\thead{Headings}} \\
    \cmidrule(l){3-5}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \thead{X} & \thead{Y} & \thead{Z} \\
    \Block[fill=red!15]{*-1}{\rotate\thead{Headings}}& \thead{A} & ax & ay & az \\
    & \thead{B} & bx & by & bz \\
    & \thead{C} & cx & cy & cz \\
    & \thead{D} & dx & dy & dz \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{NiceTabular}{@{}wc{\nicewidth}!{\vrule}*{4}{wc{\nicewidth}}@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \Block[fill=red!15]{1-*}{\thead{--------.--------}} \\
    \cmidrule(l){3-5}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \thead{X} & \thead{Y} & \thead{Z} \\
    \Block[fill=red!15]{*-1}{\rotate\thead{---------.---------}}& \thead{A} & ax & ay & az \\
    & \thead{B} & bx & by & bz \\
    & \thead{C} & cx & cy & cz \\
    & \thead{D} & dx & dy & dz \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: does this code compile?

Comment: @jsbibra: I checked again with copy+paste and yes, it does compile on my system.

Comment: @Max16hr: I'm interested to know which tool you used to add the 'spies' in the pictures...

Comment: @F.Pantigny I also I'm asking to know the tools to get the spies in the images :-)))))

Comment: Sure :) For this, I used FastStone Capture 9.4. It is a small, MS Paint based graphic tool for screenshots. And it is free. I really can recommend this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm the author of the package `nicematrix`).

---

**Concerning the rules.**

- The standard way to draw a vertical rule in `{NiceTabular}` is to use the specifier `|` in the preamble. In `{NiceTabular}`, this specifier is redefined (by comparison with the standard `|` of `{tabular}`) and the rule is drawn by PGF/Tikz. Such rule is designed to be compatible with the horizontal rules of `booktabs` (see picture). On the other side, if you put `!{\vrule}` in the preamble (as you have done), you have the standard definition of the specifier `|` in `{tabular}` and the vertical rules are not compatible with `booktabs` (however, in the spirit of `booktabs` one should never use vertical rules...).
- Concerning the horizontal rules, you have put `\cmidrule(l){3-5}`. The option `(l)` of the command `cmidrule` (which is a command of `booktabs`) shortens the rule on the left. Hence, there is no surprise in your output.

Here is the output with these two corrections.

[image: First tabular]

---

**Concerning the position of the labels in the blocks.**

The problems you have encountered arise from the instructions `@{}` you have put at both sides of your preamble.

`\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}wc{\nicewidth}!{\vrule}*{4}{wc{\nicewidth}}@{}}`

Without these intructions, the positions of the labels is less surprising.

[image: Second tabular]

What happened with those `@{}`?

- Concerning the horizontal word 'Headings', `nicematrix` prefers to center that text according to the texts present in the corresponding columns (it is *not* centerd according to the `\cmidrule`): when the block is not filled, the output seems perfect. I agree that, when the block is filled, the result may seem disappointing.
- Concerning the vertical word 'Headings', the presence of the `@{}` at the beginning of the preamble leads to an horizontal position which is not at the center of the block. But that doesn't seem to bother you (since you don't mention that point). Concerning the vertical position, it is centered corresponding the blocks boundaries as you said: it's not centered to the vertical rule you have drawn because the vertical rule you have drawn is not in the spirit of `{NiceTabular}` (a vertical rule in the spirit of `{NiceTabular}` should have been drawn by `|` in the preamble and not `!{\vrule}`).

---

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newcommand{\nicewidth}{\dimexpr .13333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{NiceTabular}{@{}wc{\nicewidth}|*{4}{wc{\nicewidth}}@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \Block[fill=red!15]{1-*}{\thead{Headings}} \\
    \cmidrule{3-5}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \thead{X} & \thead{Y} & \thead{Z} \\
    \Block[fill=red!15]{*-1}{\rotate\thead{Headings}}& \thead{A} & ax & ay & az \\
    & \thead{B} & bx & by & bz \\
    & \thead{C} & cx & cy & cz \\
    & \thead{D} & dx & dy & dz \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{NiceTabular}{wc{\nicewidth}|*{4}{wc{\nicewidth}}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \Block[fill=red!15]{1-*}{\thead{Headings}} \\
    \cmidrule{3-5}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \thead{X} & \thead{Y} & \thead{Z} \\
    \Block[fill=red!15]{*-1}{\rotate\thead{Headings}}& \thead{A} & ax & ay & az \\
    & \thead{B} & bx & by & bz \\
    & \thead{C} & cx & cy & cz \\
    & \thead{D} & dx & dy & dz \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that is a great answer! Thanks a lot for that! I was able understand all of the points you mentioned :)

I wanted to give a detailed comment on this with a subsequent question, but the comment section here is limited. So I wrote a new "answer" below, even it is more a discussion. Hope that this is okay.

Answer (score 3):

@F. Pantigny

I know that `booktabs` does not like vrules at all, what is understandable. But for me, the vertical line that I used feels more like a rotated underlining of the heading than a vertical separation of columns. A kind of rotated `\cmidrule`. Thats why I want to have this one.

This is also the reason why I do not want the vrule to touch the bottomrule. I want to keep a small gap in the sense that it is not a column separation but a kind of underlining. So I used `!{\vrule}` insted of `|` intentionally.

Thus, I need a solution how to deal with that. Have a small gap between the rules and keep the content centered to the rule.

I found a workaround for that as I kept the `!{vrule}` but added some `\hspace*{\aboverulesep}` to the row heading. That gives me the gap and the heading is centered (is it?):

```
\begin{NiceTabular}{wc{\nicewidth}!{\vrule}*{4}{wc{\nicewidth}}}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \Block{1-*}{\thead{--------.--------}} \\
  \cmidrule{3-5}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \thead{X} & \thead{Y} & \thead{Z} \\
  \Block{*-1}{\rotate{\hspace*{\aboverulesep}\thead{---------.---------}}} & \thead{A} & ax & ay & az \\
  & \thead{B} & bx & by & bz \\
  & \thead{C} & cx & cy & cz \\
  & \thead{D} & dx & dy & dz \\
  \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
```

[image]

But I think, this is not a clean "solution" because with that approach I only adjusted the vrule and the heading position but not the content of the table itself. So there must be some disproportion, I guess.

That leads to the question whether `nicematrix` provides a better way to get a gap between the table content and the `\bottomrule` (and/or to `\toprule` respectively). A clean way to lower the bottomrule without extending the blocks the same way, so that there is a gap between the bottomrule and the last blocks of the table.

With that you wouldn't have to worry about the centering anymore because you don't have to manipulate vrules or heading positions. But how to do so?

This (manipulated) image shows what I have in mind here: (Now I used filled blocks again, just to make the blocks and their boundaries visible.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@Max16hr,

As answer to your answer, I have tried to program something doing what you want (without modifying `nicematrix` and without using the internals of `nicematrix`).

You use `\TopRule` and `\BottomRule` instead of `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand{\nicewidth}{\dimexpr .13333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{tikz}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand { \TopRule } { }
  { \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_nicematrix_code_after_tl { \__max_TopRule: } }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__max_TopRule: 
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [line~width = \heavyrulewidth] 
     ([yshift=\aboverulesep]row-1-|col-1) 
      -- ([yshift=\aboverulesep]row-1-|col- \int_eval:n { \c@jCol + 1 } ) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \BottomRule } { } 
  { \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_nicematrix_code_after_tl { \__max_BottomRule: } }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__max_BottomRule: 
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [line~width = \heavyrulewidth] 
    ([yshift=-\belowrulesep]row - \int_eval:n { \c@iRow + 1 } -|col-1) 
    -- ([yshift=-\belowrulesep]row- \int_eval:n { \c@iRow + 1 } -|col- \int_eval:n { \c@jCol + 1} ) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}wc{\nicewidth}|*{4}{wc{\nicewidth}}@{}}
\TopRule
\Block{2-2}{} & & \Block[fill=red!15]{1-*}{\thead{--------.--------}} \\
\cmidrule(l){3-5}
              & & \thead{X} & \thead{Y} & \thead{Z} \\
\Block[fill=red!15]{*-1}{\rotate\thead{--------.--------}}& \thead{A} & ax & ay & az \\
& \thead{B} & bx & by & bz \\
& \thead{C} & cx & cy & cz \\
& \thead{D} & dx & dy & dz 
\BottomRule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

However, I have some remarks.

- The `\TopRule` and the `\Bottomrule` are drawn by Tikz outside the `{minipage}`.
- The command `\TopRule` is not expandable and that's why you can't put a `\multicolumn` just after the `\TopRule`. That's what I have changed and I have used a `\Block` (nevertheless, that's more in the spirit of `nicematrix`).
- Of course, I have used the standard specifier `|` in the preamble for the vertical rule since the use of `!{\rule}` was only a workaround in order to have the vertical rule not in contact with the `\bottomrule`.
- You must *not* put a `\\` at the last row before the `\BottomRule`.

Comment: Well, thank you for this, but tbh I am not satisfied :) The vertical box does not close up with the `|` on the bottom. And the gap under the `\Toprule` has a different size than the gap above the `\Bottomrule`.

Comment: Anyway, I think it is a very nice enhancement of `nicematrix` to give such `\Toprule`, `\Bottomrule` and maybe even `\Cmidrule` possibilities. Such that the user can decide whether he wants the `\toprule` / `\bottomrule` to be in touch with the blocks (and vrules) or not. I think, there are some usecases for that (as mine :P).

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution by inserting a `{NiceTabular}` inside a `{tabular}`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand{\nicewidth}{\dimexpr .13333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\toprule
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}wc{\nicewidth}|*{4}{wc{\nicewidth}}@{}}
\Block{2-2}{} & & \Block[fill=red!15]{1-*}{\thead{--------.--------}} \\
\cmidrule(l){3-5}
              & & \thead{X} & \thead{Y} & \thead{Z} \\
\Block[fill=red!15]{*-1}{\rotate\thead{--------.--------}}& \thead{A} & ax & ay & az \\
& \thead{B} & bx & by & bz \\
& \thead{C} & cx & cy & cz \\
& \thead{D} & dx & dy & dz 
\end{NiceTabular} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: :D That is cheating^^ Nice approach! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I have a solution that I like :) Centered headings, gaps (of same size) between top/bottom rule and table content and boxes that almost fit to the rules.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
  \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
  \setlength\belowrulesep{\aboverulesep}
  \newcommand{\nicewidth}{\dimexpr .128\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \toprule
    \begin{NiceTabular}{wc{\nicewidth}|*{4}{wc{\nicewidth}}}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \Block{1-*}{\thead{Headings}} \\[-\aboverulesep]
      \cmidrule{3-5}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \thead{X} & \thead{Y} & \thead{Z} \\
      \Block{*-1}{\rotate\thead{Headings}} & \thead{A} & ax & ay & az \\
      & \thead{B} & bx & by & bz \\
      & \thead{C} & cx & cy & cz \\
      & \thead{D} & dx & dy & dz
    \end{NiceTabular} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \toprule
    \begin{NiceTabular}{wc{\nicewidth}|*{4}{wc{\nicewidth}}}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \Block[fill=red!15]{1-*}{\thead{--------.--------}} \\[-\aboverulesep]
      \cmidrule{3-5}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \thead{X} & \thead{Y} & \thead{Z} \\
      \Block[fill=red!15]{*-1}{\rotate\thead{---------.---------}} & \thead{A} & ax & ay & az \\
      & \thead{B} & bx & by & bz \\
      & \thead{C} & cx & cy & cz \\
      & \thead{D} & dx & dy & dz
    \end{NiceTabular} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Only one problem is left: It seems that the vertical box does not close up with the vertical rule perfectly. On the top side it is quite good but not on the bottom. There seem to be a small overhang. Maybe this is a little bug in `nicematrix`?

Thanks again for that great help, @F. Pantigny!

Comment: As for the small overhang, I think you should post another question and I will be able to provide an answer: it will be more clear to the readers.

Comment: Finally, I managed to post that new question. You are right with that. You can find it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583853/nicematrix-overhang-of-vertical-rule-next-to-a-filled-block) :)