# NiceTabular: Overhang of vertical rule next to a filled block

Tags: tables, rules, block, nicematrix

I created a table with the `nicematrix` package. It looks quite good except of one point: I used a filled block over multiple rows with some rotated content. But the vertical rule next to the block does not close up exactly. There is a small overhang on the bottom. Why is that and how can I prevent such behaviour?

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
  \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
  \newcommand{\nicewidth}{\dimexpr .064\textwidth-\tabcolsep}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{wc{\nicewidth}|*{4}{wc{\nicewidth}}}
  \Block{2-2}{} & & \Block[fill=blue!15]{1-*}{\thead{Columns}} \\[-\aboverulesep]
  \cmidrule{3-5}
  & & \thead{X} & \thead{Y} & \thead{Z} \\
  \Block[fill=blue!15]{*-1}{\rotate\thead{Rows}} & \thead{A} & ax & ay & az \\
  & \thead{B} & bx & by & bz \\
  & \thead{C} & cx & cy & cz \\
  & \thead{D} & dx & dy & dz
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot!

(This topic is related to the following [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/582276/199357).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a new version of `nicematrix`(v. 5.13 of 2021/03/23) with a key `borders` for the command `\Block`. That key takes in as argument a (comma-separated) list of values among `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newcommand{\nicewidth}{\dimexpr .064\textwidth-\tabcolsep}
 
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{wc{\nicewidth}*{4}{wc{\nicewidth}}}
  & & \Block[fill=blue!15,borders={bottom}]{1-*}{\thead{Columns}} \\
  & & \thead{X} & \thead{Y} & \thead{Z} \\
  \Block[fill=blue!15,borders=right]{*-1}{\rotate\thead{Rows}} & \thead{A} & ax & ay & az \\
  & \thead{B} & bx & by & bz \\
  & \thead{C} & cx & \Block[fill=blue!15,borders={bottom,right}]{2-2}{}cy & cz \\
  & \thead{D} & dx & dy & dz \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Now there is a new problem^^ The gap between XYZ and the bottom border of the columns block is too small. The border should be centered as it is at the rows block's right border. Thus, somehow I have to add a `\belowrulesep` after the bottom border without extending the block itself.

Comment: You can adjust the space above X, Y and Z by adding a `\noalign{\vspace{...}}` after the first `\\` or by putting a strut (with the command `\rule`) in the row of X, Y and Z.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that is a problem but this is not a bug of `nicematrix`.

The vertical rule ends a little bit (in fact 0.5 `\arrayrulewidth`) after the expected position in order to have a perfect corner when horizontal rules are also used.

A solution would be to draw the vertical rule with Tikz in the `\CodeAfter` of the `{NiceTabular}`.

Maybe you want a more automatic approch.

It's possible. I have written in the following code a new command `\NewBlock`. That command does the job of the standard command `\Block` but has also a new key, called `borders`. The value of that key must be a comma-separated list of `north`, `east`, `south` and `west`. The corners are always correctly drawn.

This programmation does not use the internals of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\newcommand{\nicewidth}{\dimexpr .064\textwidth-\tabcolsep}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l__Max_borders_clist

\keys_define:nn { Max } { borders .clist_set:N = \l__Max_borders_clist }

\NewDocumentCommand { \MyBlock } { O { } m m }
  {
    \keys_set_known:nnN { Max } { #1 } \l_tmpa_tl
    \exp_args:NNV \Block [ \l_tmpa_tl ] { #2 } { #3 }
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l__Max_borders_clist
      {
        \__Max_cut_on_hyphen:n #2 \q_stop
        \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_nicematrix_code_after_tl 
          { 
             \__Max:nnnnn
               { \int_use:N \c@iRow } 
               { \int_use:N \c@jCol }
               { \int_eval:n { \c@iRow + \l_tmpa_int } }
               { \int_eval:n { \c@jCol + \l_tmpb_int } } 
               { \l__Max_borders_clist }
          }
      }
  }


\cs_new_protected:Nn \__Max:nnnnn
  { 
    \int_compare:nNnTF { #3 } > { 99 }
      { \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \c@iRow + 1 } }
      { \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { #3 } }
    \int_compare:nNnTF { #4 } > { 99 }
      { \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int { \c@jCol + 1 } }
      { \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int { #4 } }
    \clist_if_in:nnT { #5 } { east }  
      { 
        \tikz \draw ([yshift=0.5\arrayrulewidth]#1-|\int_use:N\l_tmpb_int) 
          -- ([yshift=0.5\arrayrulewidth]\int_use:N\l_tmpa_int-|\int_use:N\l_tmpb_int) ; 
      }
    \clist_if_in:nnT { #5 } { west }  
      { 
        \tikz \draw ([yshift=0.5\arrayrulewidth]#1-|#2) 
          -- ([yshift=0.5\arrayrulewidth]\int_use:N\l_tmpa_int-|#2) ; 
      }
    \clist_if_in:nnT { #5 } { south }  
      { 
        \clist_if_in:nnTF { #5 } { west } { \bool_set_true:N \l_tmpa_bool } { \bool_set_false:N \l_tmpa_bool }
        \use:x 
          { 
            \exp_not:N  \tikz \exp_not:N \draw 
            ( 
              [ xshift = { \bool_if:NTF \l_tmpa_bool { - 0.5 \arrayrulewidth } { 0.5 \arrayrulewidth } } ]
              \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int -| #2
            ) 
          }
        -- 
          (
            [ xshift = 0.5 \arrayrulewidth ]
            \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int -| \int_use:N \l_tmpb_int 
          ) 
          ; 
      }
    \clist_if_in:nnT { #5 } { north }  
      { 
        \clist_if_in:nnTF { #5 } { west } { \bool_set_true:N \l_tmpa_bool } { \bool_set_false:N \l_tmpa_bool }
        \use:x 
          { 
            \exp_not:N  \tikz \exp_not:N \draw 
            ( 
              [ xshift = { \bool_if:NTF \l_tmpa_bool { - 0.5 \arrayrulewidth } { 0.5 \arrayrulewidth } } ]
              #1 -| #2
            ) 
          }
        -- ( [ xshift = 0.5 \arrayrulewidth ] #1 -| \int_use:N \l_tmpb_int ) ; 
      }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__Max_cut_on_hyphen:n #1 - #2 \q_stop 
  {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { * } 
      { \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 100 } }
      { \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { #1 } }
    \str_if_eq:nnTF { #2 } { * } 
      { \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int { 100 } }
      { \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int { #2 } }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{wc{\nicewidth}*{4}{wc{\nicewidth}}}
  & & \MyBlock[fill=blue!15,borders={south}]{1-*}{\thead{Columns}} \\
  & & \thead{X} & \thead{Y} & \thead{Z} \\
  \MyBlock[fill=blue!15,borders=east]{*-1}{\rotate\thead{Rows}} & \thead{A} & ax & ay & az \\
  & \thead{B} & bx & by & bz \\
  & \thead{C} & cx & \MyBlock[fill=blue!15,borders={south,east}]{2-2}{}cy & cz \\
  & \thead{D} & dx & dy & dz \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix` you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Impressive programming skills!

Well, the `.5/arrayrulewidth` extension is only needed on the bottom. Why not on the top? – There could be a horizontal line as well but they have a nice corner anyway.
And could it be a solution to extend the bottom blocks and their fillings in equal measure?

Comment: If I extend the bottom blocks, two adjacent colored blocks will be overlapping. It won't be a good thing if you use semi-transparent colors. After reflexion, I think that I will add keys for a `\Block` to add rules on some of the sides of the block. As of now, it's only possible to draw the four sides at the same time (with the key `draw`).

Comment: No, two blocks will not overlap, because I just want to extend the lowest block, probably related to the `*` command. But anyway, even if the horizontal line will have another color than the block, there will be some overlapping. That's problematic, I agree.

Comment: Adding single rules to the block would also have the second advantage that the `\\[-\aboverulesep]` command before `\cmidrule` is redundant. That was needed to keep the block content centered vertically. But with a bottom block rule I don't need the cmidrule anymore, thus the line break can return to its normal size.

Comment: I have modified my answer. Now, it's possible to draw whatever border you want for your block. The corners are always correct.

Comment: Nice, great work! :) If you're going to integrate that into your ´nicematrix´ package, I would suggest to use the words 'top, bottom, left, right' instead of 'north, east, south, west'. This is more common, I think.

Comment: You are right...

Comment: Hi @F. Pantigny. I just want to ask, whether you still plan to extend the `draw` command for `\Block` as described? With the latest updates of `nicematrix` I don't see this posibility yet. Thank you :)

Comment: @Max26hr. It will be done soon. However, it's not straitforward because the code of `nicematrix` does not use at all Tikz but only PGF (for efficiency).That's why I have to translate the programmation that is in this answer into PGF. It will be done within a few weeks.

Comment: @Max26hr: I have posted on CTAN a new version (5.13 of 2021/03/23) which implements the key `borders` for the command `\Block`.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. I will check it out soon.